# Editor.java IndexOutOfBoundsException offset(x) should be less than line limit(y)

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hi have anyone know this crash?

Still confusing how to reproduce. From the stackTrace it is something related to Email EditText.

and majority is happen on Xiaomi's Redmi devices and 100% Android 10

Full stackTrace

```
Editor.java line 3324
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
offset(18) should be less than line limit(17)

    android.text.TextLine.measure (TextLine.java:353)
    android.text.Layout.getHorizontal (Layout.java:1213)
    android.text.Layout.getHorizontal (Layout.java:1190)
    android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal (Layout.java:1160)
    android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal (Layout.java:1149)
    android.widget.Editor$ActionPinnedPopupWindow.computeLocalPosition (Editor.java:3324)
    android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.show (Editor.java:3628)
    android.widget.Editor$ActionPinnedPopupWindow.show (Editor.java:3471)
    android.widget.Editor$EmailAddPopupWindow.show (Editor.java:4995)
    android.widget.Editor$1.run (Editor.java:1528)
    android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:914)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
    android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:225)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7563)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:539)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:994)
```

Comment: @micheal chen were you able to find any solution for this?

Comment: Hi @Shrikant, unfortunately, not yet

Comment: Shrikant @michael Did you find the cause of this error?

Comment: not yet @Siklab.ph

Answer (score 1):

```
offset(X) should be less than line limit(Y)
```

I had a similar error in Android 12+ `EditText`s. It happens when, for some reason, `EditText.getText().length()` (called **Y** in the error above) does not match the actual length of the copy-pasted text (called **X** in the error above).

Our workaround is to extend `EditText` and then manually call `setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)` (in our case, in `onTextContextMenuItem`), since it appears to correct the expected text length with the actual text length.

Comment: can i have your sample or step to reproduce how what text to be pasted? so i can test in my device. @siklah.ph

Comment: @michaelchen to reproduce, I just paste something to the edittext (without doing anything to it first. i.e. paste it imemediately)

Answer (score -1):

use the following instead

```
<your view>.post{
  <your view>.<your operation>
}
```